# SVG images not showing in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, asp-classic

I am desperately trying to get my svg image to show in a firefox browser. What do I do wrong?

I have read that I should use the  for inserting svg graphics. Best practice I guess.

On this site http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/displaying-svg-in-web-browsers.html  they say I should set the content type in the HTTP response, but I cant figure out the exact code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Testsite here: http://e-kl.dk/test5.asp

Code here:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="1252"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ernst + Kindt-Larsen Arkitekter</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a.svg {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block; 
}
a.svg:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menulinje">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="20" colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td width="8" class="txt_EKL_menu_aktiv">&nbsp;</td>
    <td height="26" valign="middle"><a href="test2.asp" class="svg"><object type="image/svg+xml" data="Images/EKLlogo.svg" height="30" width="500" codebase="http://www.savarese.com/software/svgplugin/"></object></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the codebase attribute on the `<object>` element and it will display.